# Generic translator for Enums

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, enums

I am using Spring 3, Hibernate and JSP. My User entity has a field gender that is of type Enum. When I am displaying this field in a form, I would like to have the options localized. The question is: is there a way to make all the enums used by my entities to be localized when displayed?

Answer (score 6):

Let's assume we have the following enum and we need to localize it

```
package com.foo.enums;

public enum Color {
    RED, GREEN, BLUE;
}
```

In the messages files (e.g. messages_de.properties) the following codes have to be define

```
colors.RED=rot
colors.GREEN=grün
colors.BLUE=blau
```

Finally, the jsp view should look like it shown below

```
<c:forEach items="${colors}" var="color">
    <c:set value="colors.${color }" var="colorMessage"  />

    <spring:message code="${colorMessage }"/>
</c:forEach>
```

Also, you may define the message codes directly in your enum as the following

```
package com.scriptico.blog.sw.enums;

public enum Color {
    RED("colors.RED"), GREEN("colors.GREEN"), BLUE("colors.BLUE");

    private String messageCode;

    private Color(final String messageCode) {
        this.messageCode = messageCode;
    }

    public String getMessageCode() {
        return messageCode;
    }
}
```

and then just use messageCode in the message tag

```
<c:forEach items="${colors}" var="color">
    <spring:message code="${color.messageCode }"/>
</c:forEach>
```